# How to manage viewmodel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have an activity that has a view model. When I call 2 methods of that view model first execute second method. Why?

How can I manage that methods?

This is onCreate of the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_news_letter);

    dbViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(DBViewModel.class);

    dbViewModel.getLastUpdate().observe(this, s -> {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(s);
            timeStamp = (int)date.getTime() / 1000;
            getAllNews(BaseCodeClass.CompanyID, timeStamp);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    dbViewModel.getAllNews().observe(this, newsLetters ->
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });

}
```

In this method first dbViewModel.getAllNews() is executed then dbViewModel.getLastUpdate()

Comment: Do you actually mean that those lines are executed the wrong way around? Or is the code inside of the observer executed the wrong way around?

Comment: the code inside of the observer executed wrong. I believe it's not wrong, I can not manage them. I wanna execute the first onChange at first then the second one

Comment: Right, well the answer from @cd1 is correct. If you need them to be executed in a specific order then you're probably not using the pattern correctly. Without more details it's hard to see what you're doing wrong, the code you've provided wouldn't have any problems as far as I can see.

Comment: @HenryTwist When I use getValue() base on cd1's answer, it returns null

Comment: Yes like the answer says, wherever your data is coming from clearly takes time, which means you obviously have to call `getValue` when the data is available. Generally observing the data is enough, otherwise the `LiveData` is probably redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you observe a `LiveData`, it will call the `onChanged` method on its observers when the data is ready or when the data changes. When you observe two or more `LiveData`s in a certain order, it doesn't mean that the observers will be called in that order as well. It will happen sometime when the data is ready. That's exactly the behavior of observable fields like `LiveData`.

If you want to read those values in that exact order and only once, you can call `getValue()` and get the value right away instead of observing them:

```
String s = dbViewModel.getLastUpdate().getValue();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
try {
    Date date = format.parse(s);
    timeStamp = (int)date.getTime() / 1000;
    getAllNews(BaseCodeClass.CompanyID, timeStamp);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

var newsLetters = dbViewModel.getAllNews().getValue();
Toast.makeText(this, "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Those values will be read in that order, but they won't be called again if the `LiveData` values change.

Comment: When I use getValue(), s becomes null. So application crashes.

Comment: That means those values haven't been set inside the ViewModel yet. After the ViewModel is initialized, depending on its implementation, the LiveData data may still be unset. If you don't call setValue on the LiveData during the ViewModel constructor, it's likely the LiveData will be set a bit later, thus you get null in your code in that moment. That's why it's usually better to call observe and wait for the data to be populated so you're sure you'll get something. But that isn't a synchronous set of operations.